How to calculate: $\lim_{t\to\infty} \frac1{\log(t^2+1/t^2)}\int_1^{\pi t}\frac{\sin^2(5x)}x\,dx=\frac14$

Q.52 The value of
$$\lim_{t\to\infty} \frac1{\log\left(t^2+\frac1{t^2}\right)}\int_1^{\pi t}\frac{\sin^2(5x)}x\,dx$$
equals _____ (rounded off to two decimal places).

By using brute force calculation, the limit is $\frac14$ but how can i easily solve this????
This question was asked in IIT jam 2024, since 2 month I am unable to solve this question. I tried L'hopital, but I know L'hopital's rule won't work because after differentiating both function and for specific value of $t$ the limit becomes $0$ but for another value of $t$ it still remains in indeterminate form....

it's hard to read

@SineoftheTime i have added picture

You asked this question already. Instead of re-posting, you should simply edit the original to include the context you've added here. (An edit will "bump" the question to the top of the Unanswered queue, so you get that benefit of a re-post without cluttering the site with duplicates.)

$$\frac1{\log\left(t^2+\frac1{t^2}\right)}\int_1^{\pi t}\frac{\sin^2(5x)}x,dx\sim\frac1{2\ln t}\int_1^{\pi t}\frac{1-\cos(10x)}{2x}dx\sim\frac1{4\ln t}\int_{1/\pi}^t\frac{dt}t$$
